# Using Owl Carousel with Ember

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, owl-carousel

Ember.js uses script tags for databinding within the DOM, and owl-carousel picks up on the script tags and adding them as elements within the slider. Is there a way to ignore those script tags. ie:

[image]

```
<div id="slider-nav">
   {{#each playlist.videos}}
      {{series-slider title=title series=series featured=featured img=thumbnail_image vid_id=youtube_video_id description=description background=hero_image}}
   {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: Use the unbound helper. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_unbound

Comment: @blessenm I can't when its setup like this.

Comment: Can you create a failing jsbin. It will help others to find a solution.

Comment: metal views got merged into master. This basically gets rid of metamorph(script tags) library. You can build the source. Should solve ur problems. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/5432

Comment: @blessenm peeerrrfect timing! this is amazing! The DOM is so clean!

Comment: Do you have a public repo available for reference. I'm new to Ember and trying to implement an owl carousel in and Ember-CLI app myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option in owl-carousel2 - "nestedItemSelector". This can be used to tell owl-carousel which item it should identify as child items & ignore others.

```
/* Thumb Slider Starts*/
$('.fivecolumn.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop:false,
  margin:20,
  responsiveClass:true,
  nestedItemSelector: 'listItem',
  responsive:{
    0:{
      items:1,
      nav:true
    },
    380:{
      items:2,
      nav:false
    },
    600:{
      items:3,
      nav:false
    },
    1000:{
      items:5,
      nav:true,
      loop:false
    }
  }
})
```